# Openable & Closable Objects for Unreal Engine

Tags: mesh

I'm curious how people create objects that are openable and closable, whether it is a small box or a car that has parts that can be opened. If I want to create something in Blender (later would be used in UE) should  I use an Armature like for characters, or there is something other, better method for these kind of interactable objects?

Comment: The easiest way if the movable part is a separate object and the animation (or constraint) is created in the Game Engine.

Comment: And where should the origins of the objects be located? Should they be at the same point as the parent/main object or at the point where it'll rotate?

Comment: Probably where it rotates. In UE4 all of the fbx meshes has their origin at the world origin when imported. So don't forget to reset the location (ctrl+a on default) in blender before export them. Or you can export the meshes with all the origins at the same location, then add empties (scene objects) to the hinge points in the blueprints and assign the meshes as children of them. The first method will give simplier blueprints but needs a bit adjustment to place the moving parts. In the second case everything will be at the right place, but needs a few extra object.